# Characterization of Fuchsian groups containing hyperbolic elements

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-actions, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I want to find the Fuchsian groups that acts on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ to give $n$-holed torus $\mathbb{T_n}$. I am following the book **Fuschian Groups** by **Svetlana Katok**. There's this corollary-

> **Corollary 4.2.7.** A Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ is cocompact if and only if $\mu(\mathbb{H}/\Gamma)<\infty$ and $\Gamma$ contains no parabolic elements.

where cocompact Fuschian groups are defined as follows-

> **Definition.** A Fuchsian group is said to be cocompact if $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is compact.

To get $\mathbb{T_n}$ as quotient $\Gamma$should act freely on $\mathbb{H}$. Therefore $\Gamma$ can't contain elliptic elements as elliptic elements fixes two points in $\mathbb{H}$. So by above corollary, the only choice we have is hyperbolic elements.

From here, I want to show that $\Gamma$ is genrated by $2n$ elements where $n\in \mathbb{N}−\{1\}$, more precisely $\Gamma = \langle a_1,b_1,...,a_n,b_n | a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}...a_nb_na_n^{-1}b_n^{-1}=1\rangle $

Comment: Do you know the classification of isometries of hyperbolic plane (hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptic)?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. I am not sure I understand the question on what sort of constraints you are looking to get from a group $\Gamma$ by looking at its group structure? Also not sure what kind of Möbius transformations you are asking about? You might be interested in moduli spaces of hyperbolic surfaces or Teichmüller theory(basically spaces of $\Gamma$ up to certain equivalences in these cases).

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes. I know the classification of isometries of hyperbolic plane as hyperbolic, parabolic and elliptic.

Comment: @PaulPlummer: $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$. So we can view it as subgroup of Möbius transformations which contains elements of the form $f(x)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, ad-bc=1$ that act properly discontinuously.  To avoid fixed points, i. e. to make the action free, $f$ cannot be elliptic since elliptic Möbius transformations fixes two points of $\mathbb{H}$. By above corollary, $f$ cannot be parabolic.  So it has to be hyperbolic (obviously except identity transformation) i.e. $a+d >2$.

Comment: So what is your question? The statements are clear, the question(s) are not.

Comment: Is the question what traces can show up or something like that?

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Fundamental group of $\mathbb{T_n}$ is $\langle a_1,b_1,...,a_n,b_n | a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}...a_nb_na_n^{-1}b_n ^{-1}=1 \rangle$. Since $\pi_1(\mathbb{H}/\Gamma)$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma, \pi_1(\mathbb{T_n})=\pi_1(\mathbb{H}/\Gamma)=\Gamma$. Now I want to obtain the relation (without using fundamental group) that $\Gamma$ is finitely generated, more precisely it is generated by $2n$ elements.

Comment: Cool, if that is the question you actually want to ask/ what you mean by constraints/ what Mobius transformations there are you should edit the question.

Comment: Your question in the latest comment is very different from what is written in the post. Proving that Γ is $2n$ generated w/o using the fundamental group is not hard. However, I do not see why you are reluctant to use the Van Kampen's theorem, it was proven for a reason, to make computations like this relatively effortless.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: The question in comment is the thing I want to prove further. I was not sure if it is right. How to show that $\Gamma$ is $2n-$ generated?  I cannot use Van Kampen's theorem because it does use fundamental groups.

Comment: Please, edit your question to reflect what you actually want to know, then I can write an answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The book you are reading essentially contains an answer to your question. Start with your genus $n$ surface $S$ and represent it as  a 4n-gon $P$ with the standard identification. Recall also that $S=H^2/\Gamma$. The next step is a bit tricky: Lift the polygon $P$ to the hyperbolic plane, to a polygon $\tilde{P}$. There will be $2n$  elements $a_1, b_1...,a_{n}, b_n$ of $\Gamma$ which pair the sides of $\tilde{P}$. The existence of a lift  requires some work. For instance, if you know covering theory, use the fact that $P$ is simply-connected. Or use the *monodromy principle* from the complex analysis. It all depends on what kind of math you know. Now, apply Theorem 3.5.4 from Katok's book to conclude that $a_1, b_1...,a_{n}, b_n$ generate $\Gamma$. Katok proves this theorem assuming that $\tilde{P}$ is a Dirichlet domain of $\Gamma$, but it is not really needed for the proof. You only need the fact that $\tilde{P}$ is a fundamental domain. One can even compute the presentation of $\Gamma$ using $\tilde{P}$ and its side-pairing, but that would require reading a different book. I think, it is in Maskit's book "Kleinian Groups."