# Evenly generated Fuchsian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, riemann-surfaces

Consider the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ and a Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ (i. e. a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ that acts freely and properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$.

I want to show that if $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is compact then $\Gamma$ is genrated by $2n$ number of elements where $n\in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$.

**My attempt :**

$PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to the group of all Möbius transformations $f$ on $\mathbb{H}$ where $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}; a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, ad-bc=1$. Since elliptic elements (i.e. elements with $(a+d)^2<4$) fix $2$ points of $\mathbb{H}$, $\Gamma$ does not contain elliptic elements.

Also a corollary from the book **Fuchsian Groups** by **Svetlana Katok** says-

> **Corollary 4.2.7.** A Fuchsian group $G$ is cocompact if and only if $\mu(\mathbb{H}/G)<\infty$ and $G$ contains no non-identity parabolic elements.

where a Fuchsian group $G$ is said to be cocompact if $\mathbb{H}/G$ is compact.

Therefore $\Gamma$ does not contain non-identity parabolic elements (i.e. elements with $(a+b)^2=4$).

Thus, so far what I could get is $\Gamma$ can contain only hyperbolic elements (i. e. elements with $(a+d)^2>4$). I have no idea how to proceed further. How can one prove that $\Gamma$ is generated by $2n$ elements where $n\in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$.

Comment: Hint: If $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated infinite group, you can always find a finite generating set of even cardinality. Actually, for every sufficiently large $N$, $\Gamma$ has a generating set of cardinality $N$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan how can we say $\Gamma $ is finitely generated?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650719/characterization-of-fuchsian-groups-containing-hyperbolic-elements/3655512#3655512).

Comment: @MoisheKohan But that is a particular case.  In my question we don't know if the quotient is a genus $n$ surface.

Comment: Why not? Don't you already know that the quotient is a compact surface? Did you already learn a classification of surfaces? One usually learns this before studying Fuchsian groups?

Comment: @MoisheKohan If one is not aware of the classification of compact surfaces or don't want to use the classification of compact surfaces, how to prove the result?

Comment: You can then use [Švarc–Milnor lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0varc%E2%80%93Milnor_lemma).